# Embed Facebook Page Plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugin, embed

I've been following facebook instructions in order to embed their "page plugin" in my website, and failing. ([See instructions here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin))

Would you please take a look at my code and help me out? thanks in advance!

```
    <body>

<!-- Include the JavaScript SDK -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Include the plugin  -->

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/instagram" 
  data-width="280" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false"
  data-show-posts="true"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add the first part (everything between the `<!-- Include the JavaScript SDK -->` lines) just after your `</body>` tag. keep the last part where it is.

Comment: Thanks Johnny, that was it... i just stuffed all the SCRIPT right after the plugin's DIV...

Comment: @johnny_s "just after your </body> tag"? Nothing should come after the closing `body` tag, except the closing `html` tag? The FB docs state "right after the opening `<body>` tag" - so _inside_ the `body` - which is actually how the OP has it?!

Comment: it's now working for him so it must have worked?

Comment: I simply changed order to those coding blocks... first the plugin, then the java sdk... Bam! works fine: http://www.yerbabuenaya.com Thanks!

Comment: @johnny_s The point of my comment was that it's _invalid_ HTML to include this code _after_ the closing `</body>` tag. If you were to move it anywhere, you would put it _before_ the closing `body` tag (still _inside_ the `body` element) - which is actually what the OP has done.

Comment: The example code above works OK as is. The placement of the Facebook JavaScript SDK is not so critical in order to get it to "work". If it wasn't working initially on your site then it would seem that "something else" (other page elements perhaps) were conflicting?

Comment: That's what i thought at first.. maybe a facebook thing.. checking ownership of the site or something like that? I don't know... All I know is it works fine just by placing the script inside the body tag, right after the plugin. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple placement error, you have your javascript within the `<body>` tags whereas they should be outside of it.

Just move your first seven lines of code so that they are after your  tags. See below;

```
<!-- Include the JavaScript SDK -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- Include the plugin  -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution was quite simple:

I just added the script section INSIDE body tag, right AFTER the plugin and it started working.

Thanks!